# Inbrowser android api's

Tags: android, html, api, web-applications

I'm trying to make an in-browser web appliction for mobile phones. We started with an Android system, because it was the most open for development.

Now I want to make it for all the other OS's too, and I've heard that we can make a website into an app. We saw this live on a IPad and a Android tablet.

If you open it on your tablet they ask "Would you make an app from this website?". If you do this them make a kind of link to you website. What google maps does is that they ask for permission to get your GPS data. We want to do the same with Bluetooth.

My question now is, does anybody know a good example where I can take a look how to do it?

Also I want to know if its possible to do it all in HTML, or do I need a webview layer above it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are asking for Apache [PhoneGap](http://prohegap.com)

> PhoneGap is a mobile development framework produced by Nitobi, purchased by Adobe Systems. It enables software programmers to build applications for mobile devices using JavaScript, HTML5 and CSS3, instead of device-specific languages such as Objective-C

or other [Multiple phone web-based application framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_phone_web_based_application_framework)